# handlebars find and retrieve object based on other object iteration

Tags: object, handlebars.js

i have an array holding objects from the server like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

so i'm doing an `#each` on that array, and i'm starting to display each value in the current object using the `this` keyword for example :

```
{{#if this.recommendations_received}}
 {{this.recommendations_received.length}} recommendations
{{else}}
 No recommendations
{{/if}}
```

each object has an id like so :

```
object : { id: "someid" ,
         recommendations_received: [
          {
            recommendation_id: "some_ID",
            giver: {
            giver_id: "the_giver_id",
            name: "the_giver_name"
          }
        }
     ]}
```

so i'm doing another iteration to show each recommendation like so:

```
{{#each this.recommendations_received}}
  {{this.giver.name}}
{{/each}}
```

but now i need also to iterate over the giver categories array. which simply look like this

```
categories : [object, object, object]
```

inside each object in categories i have name and title.

i want to get the categories of the giver recommendation inside the #each helper that i did for recommendation_received based on the id of the giver which is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how is giver and categories related to each, but you need to combine your objects before passing to handlebars. The easier way is to simply combine both objects by nesting the categories object inside the giver object. The other way would be to create a wrapper object to hold your main array and the categories array before passing to handlebars.